# How I can render a dynamic antd icons components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, antd

I'm trying to render an antd icons dynamically Here is my function but it doesn't work even after using react-html-parser

```
let ratingClal = (nOfStars)=>{
    let stars = "";

    for(let i=0; i < nOfStars; i++){
        stars+="<StarFilled />";
    }

    stars = <p>{ ReactHtmlParser(stars) }</p>;
    return stars;
}
```

Comment: What are you calling from nOfStars?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer that solves the problem using `react-html-parser`. Are you sure you need that library to solve your problem?

If you want to render a list of react components, that can be done using standard React.

```js
const Star = () => <span>*</span>;

const stars = n => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result.push(<Star />);
  }

  return <p>{result}</p>;
};
```

You can see it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-4t6vv?file=/index.js:115-285).